# How to select specific tag's attribute value with xPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I need to get the text from,
`<option value="......" >.......`, But except first option tag.

My code is:

```
"xPath":"descendant::div[contains(@class,'produit__select')]/descendant::select[@name='select0']/descendant::option[@disabled='disabled']/value"
```

I can't get the results. Can some one help me this?

```
<div class="produit__select">
 <label for="select0">Parfum</label>
 <select name="select0" id="select0">
   <option disabled="disabled">Faites un choix</option>  
   <option value="835">Pommes de Nouvelle Aquitaine</option> 
   <option value="842">Pommes Nectarines Bananes</option>
   <option value="838">Pommes Pruneaux</option>
   <option value="839" selected="selected">Pommes Fraises</option>
   <option value="841">Pommes Cassis</option>
   <option value="840">Pommes Bananes Kiwi</option>
   <option value="836">Pommes Poires</option>
   <option value="837">Pommes Coings</option> 
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, copy-paste the XML as text, not as an image. We can't try our solutions on a PNG image.

Comment: I have done, is it clear for you pls?

Comment: Thanks a lot @choroba, your code is fine, but I'm not getting my desired results on web crawling.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `//` instead of `descendant::`. Also, there's no element named `value`. If you are interested in the text, use the `text()` function, if you want to skip the first child, make sure the `position()` of the child is greater than 1.

```
//div[contains(@class,'produit__select')]
/select[@name='select0']
/option[position()>1]/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another option to skip disabled one.

```
//div[@class='produit__select']/select[@name='select0']/option[not(contains(@disabled,'disabled'))]/text()
```

**DEMO:**

[image]